# Does this answer your question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Nach einem *vote to close* aufgrund eines Duplikats wird automatisch ein Kommentar hinterlegt, der auf die bereits gestellte / beantwortete Frage hinweist.

Dieser Kommentar beginnt mit: *Does this answer your question?*

Das kommt mir seltsam vor. Sollte das hier nicht besser auf Deutsch gefragt werden?

*Beantwortet das deine Frage ...*

Answer (score 1):

Nachdem hier ausdrücklich englische und deutsche Fragen erlaubt sind, kann man davon ausgehen, dass der typische Seitenbesucher beides zumindest versteht. Unter einer englischen Frage wirkte der deutsche Satz auch deplatziert, hat aber nicht das Argument der Forenuniversalität auf seiner Seite.

Eine von der Sprache der Frage abhängige Lösung ist vermutlich den Aufwand nicht wert.

Answer (score 0):

Warum ist das überhaupt als Frage formuliert - unabhängig davon, ob auf Englisch oder Deutsch? Der Umstand, die Frage geschlossen zu haben, impliziert doch schon, daß es so ist, denn wenn das, was man da als Link angibt, die Frage *nicht* beantwortet, dann hätte man sie vielleicht besser offengelassen.

Comment: Die Rede ist von dem Kommentar, der bei einem Close-Vote automatisch gesetzt wird. Das heißt ja noch nicht, dass die Frage tatsächlich geschlossen wird, sondern gibt dem Fragensteller die Gelegenheit zu erläutern, warum die Frage ggf. kein Duplikat ist.

Comment: Es kann Dissens darüber bestehen, was der Gegenstand der Frage ist. Insbesondere kann die Person, die die Frage stellt, meinen, dass sie eigentlich etwas anderes fragen wollte. Dann kann die Frage im automatisch generierten Kommentar ein Anlass sein, die eigene Frage anders zu formulieren, um das Missverständnis auszuräumen.